# Как выполнить фильтрацию массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, filter

У меня есть список списков чисел в строковом выражении (после парсинга CSV файла). Надо оставить только списки, у которых первый элемент больше 0.

Делаю так:

```
data = filter(lambda record: int(record[0]) >= 0, src_data)
```

Все ок.

Поскольку дальше будет выборка чисел в NumPy массивы, то решил работать с NumPy массивами сразу, т.е. парсинг CSV файла сразу идет в NumPy массив и дальше работа только с такими данными.

Поэтому, для фильтрации использую следующий код:

```
data = src_data[np.array(src_data[:, 0], int) >= 0]
```

И вот тут выдает ошибку:

> data = src_data[np.array(src_data[:, 0], int) >= 0]
>
> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Для меньшего размера массивов, все нормально, но если мне из массива нужно лишь какое-то небольшое кол-во элементов, то можно сделать так:

```
data = src_data[:32][np.array(src_data[:32, 0], int) >= 0]
```

И тоже все нормально.

Но можно ли через numpy сделать нормальную фильтрацию больших массивов или использовать только родной питоновский `filter`?

P.S. из CSV сразу все не перевожу в тот же `int`, потому что некоторые столбцы нужны как `int`, другие как `float` и т.д..

Comment: странно, что это связано с длинной массива. по идее, ошибка вызвана длиной  числа, а numpy пытается сохранять его как int. видимо, надо переводить во float

Comment: @splash58, ну это моя гипотеза была, но в данных нет больших чисел, вот в чем дело то! и когда я фильтрацию делаю через `filter` и лишь потом перегоняю в numpy массив такой ошибки не возникает

Comment: может, вам везет, и в отфильтрованных значениях нет длинных чисел ? :) ошибка, вроде, олнозначная

Comment: а зачем вы вообще переводите object в число при фильтрации? если фильтровать как текст?

Comment: @splash, вы были правы, посмотрел глазами и есть числа больше 2 миллиардов, и 32битное представление знакового целого уже не подходит и нужно использовать `np.uint64`!

Comment: @strawdog, а как вы определите в строке, что внутри число больше 0?

Comment: @Zhihar по знаку минус :)))

Comment: @splash58, ну это уже хитро сравнивать, а хочется же однозначной универсальности - раз там число то и работать надо как с счислом

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов несколько. Можно перевести в `np.float`, но нужно подбирать размер, при котором вам хватит разрядов и ничего не исказится (`float` - не точный тип). Но может хватить и `np.int` какого-то размера. Можно потестировать разные варианты, код на примере максимума взятого как `sys.maxsize+1`. Проверю, вылетит ли `exception` и какова будет разница между тем, что поместилось в массив и `sys.maxsize+1`:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
for dtype in [int,np.float,np.float16,np.float32,np.int32,np.int64,np.uint64]:
    preds = np.zeros((1, 3), dtype=dtype)
    print(preds.dtype, end=': ')
    p = [sys.maxsize+1]
    try:
        preds[0] = p
        print(preds[0]-p)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Вывод:

```
int64: Python int too large to convert to C long
float64: [0. 0. 0.]
float16: [inf inf inf]
float32: [0. 0. 0.]
int32: Python int too large to convert to C long
int64: Python int too large to convert to C long
uint64: [0 0 0]
```

Пока я писал код вроде уже разобрались в чём дело, но пусть уж будет.

Как видно, в случае с `sys.maxsize+1` из `int`-ов подходит только `uint64`, но это беззнаковый тип, в случае отрицательных чисел будет фигня. Видимо, всё же `float` более универсален, начиная с `float32`.

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо @splash58, проблема действительно была в том, что внутри данных находилось число, которое выходило за диапазон 32битных чисел (3.290.802.160), поэтому при переводе надо было явно указать, что мне нужны целые побольше:

```
data = src_data[np.array(src_data[:, 0], np.uint64) >= 0]
```

Просто думал, что int у numpy такой же неограниченный как у голого python, ну и конечно не думал, что в данных такие большие числа появятся

Comment: Питоновский `int`, насколько я помню, бесконечен. Но именно за счёт этого он не может быть оптимально оптимизирован. А вот `int`-ы `numpy` - они имеют конкретное число разрядов и сильно оптимизированы, как и всё остальное в `numpy`.

Answer (score 3):

> У меня есть список списков чисел в строковом выражении (**после парсинга CSV файла**).

Мне кажется многих проблем можно избежать если правильно читать исходные данные, тогда и преобразования типов не нужно будет делать.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=np.uint64)
```

также можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype="uint64")
```

Comment: дело в том, некоторые столбцы у меня целочисленные, а некоторые с плавающей запятой

Comment: @Zhihar, это не проблема. В таких вопросах нужно всегда приводить воспроизводимые примеры данных. Иначе чаще всего обе стороны впустую потратят время...